# rsync exculde dir and all sub dirs

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm trying to use Rsync to sync some of by data but I'm unable to exclude what I want
this is my directory tree:

```
tst/
├── st1
│   ├── st11
│   │   └── txt.text
│   ├── st12
│   ├── st13
│   ├── st14
│   └── st15
├── st2
├── st3
├── st4
└── st5
```

i want wo exclude dir st1 and all subdir and files underit.
i tried using this tutorial [this tutorial](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-exclude-files-and-directories-with-rsync/) with no luck.
this are the command that i tried:

```
rsync -auvzhe --exclude 'tst/st1/' --exclude 'tst/st1/*/' --exclude 'tst/st1' tst  /home/yaodav/Desktop/shared_folder/BU/
```

also this one:

```
rsync -auvzhe --exclude 'tst/st1/' --exclude 'tst/st1/*/' tst  /home/yaodav/Desktop/shared_folder/BU/
```

Comment: What happens? Does it fails with an output error? Does the directory is still being uploaded?

Comment: yes the Dir still bing uploads

Comment: According to the article you referenced to - "When excluding files or directories you need to use their relative paths to the source directory." Try excluding the directory by its relative path - `rsync - auvzhe - - exclude st1 tst /home/yaodav/Desktop/shared_folder/BU/`